# How do I edit a migration in laravel framework?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to modify a migration

here is the migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers.blade.php', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers.blade.php');
    }
}
```

I have added the email part but when I tried to use rollback, I am getting this error

```
Rolling back: 2019_10_06_090218_create_customers_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ".": syntax error (SQL: drop table if exists "customers"."blade"."php")

  at /Users/macair13/blog/meatrack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ".": syntax error")
      /Users/macair13/blog/meatrack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:453

  2   PDO::prepare("drop table if exists "customers"."blade"."php"")
      /Users/macair13/blog/meatrack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:453

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem because for myself, I cannot see what is wrong with what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the table name instead of a view name

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Here
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // And here
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

The `name.blade.php` is reserved for HTML views

Answer (score 1):

You migration syntax is wrong

WHen you add a column in the "up" handler, it is advisable to removed it in the "down" handle function.

In your case, you did add "name" column" and the down would remove an entire table (malformulated  though)!

```
public function down()
{
    $table->dropColumn('name');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong table name on schema, please replace that with following

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then just run an artisan command

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify/rollback already deployed migrations.

If it's still only in your development database, you can just reset the database. (`php artisan migrate:fresh`)

... and as was already mentioned in other answers, you are probably using wrong table name. Migrations have nothing to do with your view (HTML template) file name.